# How to use a library that imports memcache in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to use a library (memorised) that uses memcache like this: `import memcache`

Now on App Engine, memcache must be imported like this: `from google.appengine.api import memcache`

So I get this error when running with dev_appserver.py: `ImportError: No module named memcache`

Can I use this library without modifying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: even if you can get the module to work on a local instance using `dev_appserver.py`, because Google controls the server environment, you can only use their supported modules when you upload your code to their hosting services. See [here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)

The long answer is that, in order to `import memcache`, you will need the `memcache` package installed. If you want to try to use the memcache module that Google provides instead, you can change that to `from google.appengine.api import memcache`, but Google's memcache may have substantial and significant differences from the standard Python memcache package that memorised uses, and it may throw errors or not work at all. Furthermore, even if you do get memorised to work, you won't be able to use it on Google's servers, as it is not a supported third-party library (see above).

Answer (score 2):

Assume that app engine's memcache is identical with memcached library.. So, how about to create memcache.py module with:

```
from google.appengine.api.memcache import *
```

And then memorised will be able to use memcache.set(), memcache.get(), etc. after importing memcache.

Answer (score 2):

To further clarify jayhendren's answer - if you are planning to use GAE's memcache service, you must use

from google.appengine.api import memcache

you cannot use an open source memcache library. The only scenario where you could use the standard python memcache lib is if you were running your own memcache service somewhere (e.g. on Compute Engine) and you wanted to connect out to that over a socket. I'm guessing you're not doing that.

Assuming you want to use GAE's built in memcache service:  since there are differences between the API defined by GAE's memcache lib and the standard python memcache libs, you will have to make some minor changes to memorised so that it can successfully talk to the GAE memcache library. For the most part though the developer facing functionality is the same as the standard python lib. If you get it working, let us know!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to manually alter sys.path with GAE API modules path before importing memorised:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/')
```

Don't know about memorised, but just

```
import memcache
```

works.